# Why does the list item remain after it has been spliced out?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, splice

An input takes a list item, let's say a name.

On entering the name, it gets added to an array, and displayed in html in a div.

Then we have an area to delete a name off of the list if it is matched.

The problem comes after deleting a list item. When the next item is entered, the deleted name shows up as well. I have good remarks on the code pen, where I am trying to hammer out all of the details of this before I move it to a more permanent place. Thank you in advance.

[code pen](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/pOdRpg)

```
var userInputArr = [];
function inputNames(){
  var userInput = $('#userInput').val();
  userInputArr.push(userInput);
  if(userInput !== ' '){
    $("#listDisplayDiv").html(userInputArr.join(','));
  $('#userInput').val(' ');
    $('#userInput').html(' ');
  }else{
    alert('add name');
  }

}


//clear item from list

function clearItem(){
  var listValue = $('#listDisplayDiv').html();
  var listValArr = listValue.split(',');
  var itemToClear = $('#clearItemInput').val();
  var indexOfSearch = listValArr.indexOf(itemToClear);
  listValArr.splice(indexOfSearch, 1);
  $('#listDisplayDiv').html(listValArr.join(','));


}
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: The `inputNames()` function adds the name to `userInputArr`. `clearItem()` doesn't remove it from that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing it from the userInputArr, so add something like this in your `clearItem()` function.

```
userInputArr.splice(userInputArr.indexOf(itemToClear), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you input a new name, it adds the name to the `userInputArr` global variable, and uses this to produce the contents of `#listDisplayDiv`.

When you clear a name, you remove it from `#listDisplayDiv`, but don't remove it from `userInputArr`. So the next time you add a name, you regenerate the DIV contents from that array, which has all the old names.

You need to be consistent. Either both functions should split the HTML, update that array, and then join it to produce the DIV contents, or both should use the `userInputArr` variable.